# Image and Kernel of matrices that have no rows of zeroes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have two matrices $A_T, A_V \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times s}$ with $Image(A_T) = Image(A_V)$ and both have no rows of only zero elements. The image of the matrices are generated by the non-negative integer system of generators $t_1, \dots, t_s$ and $v_1, \dots, v_s$ respectively. Now, I am interested whether we could draw any conclusion from that. Does it hold that the kernels are the same?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that the kernels are the same.  For example, consider
$$
A_T = \pmatrix{1&2\\1&2}, \quad
A_V = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$
Because the two matrices have the same image, there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $A_T = A_VS$.